# Node-http-proxy: Requests on ressources get redirected to index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-proxy

I encountered a problem using node.js with the node-http-proxy module.
On some webpages resources are not loaded, because the server redirects the request to the original html file. So for every picture or css file, the index.html file is loaded again. The strange thing is that this does not happen on all websites but only on some.
Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
var router = express.Router();
var proxy = new httpProxy.createProxyServer();

router.get('/:url', function(req, res) {
    var options = {
        target: {
            host: req.params.url,
            port: 80,
            path: 'http://'
        },
        timeout: 5000,
        proxyTimeout: 5000,
        xfwd: true,
        prependPath: true
    };
    proxy.web(req, res, options);
});
```

An example for a webpage where this does not work ist http://www.kicker.de
I already tried several options, like hostRewrite or changeOrigin but those do not seem to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly encourage you to use the npm module `request`.  I have issues with other approaches fetching files over http and https with redirects.  `request` handles it quite well.  Here is some code I have to fetching content.

```
var request = require("request");

...

function fetchImage(url, callback) {
    var file, tmpFile;

    async.waterfall([
        function (next) {
            tmp.file(next);
        },
        function (location, descriptior, cleanupCallback, next) {
            console.log(location);
            tmpFile = location + ".png"
            console.log("fetching", url, "and saving it as", tmpFile);
            var download = request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tmpFile));

            download.on("finish", function(){
                console.log("finished downloading picture", tmpFile);
                fs.stat(tmpFile, next)
            });
        }
    ], callback);
}
```